# Test execution causing Eventbrite error -

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I have a method that creates a simple Account/Opportunity pair which works successfully in developer console:-

```
  //  @isTest
public with sharing class testSalesProcess {


  // @isTest
    public static void testOpportunity1(){

        Account a = new Account(name='Lorem Ipsum');
        insert a;


        Opportunity opty = new Opportunity();
        opty.CloseDate = Date.today()+1;
        opty.Name = 'Opty1';
        opty.Amount = 2000;
        opty.StageName = 'Qualification';
        opty.AccountId = a.id;
        insert opty;

    }
}
```

If I create an Opportunity with the same criteria in the UI by hand then this saves successfully.

When I switch this over to @isTest and run under test execution then this fails with an error in EventbriteSync.EventbriteOpportunityTrigger. As this is a managed package I can't see what is the problem - any ideas?

I can't understand why it works in 'non test mode' but fails in test. The Eventbrite tests run fine btw.

Error Message is:-

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, EventbriteSync.EventbriteOpportunityTrigger: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Trigger.EventbriteSync.EventbriteOpportunityTrigger: line 4, column 1: []
```

Comment: Do you have an error code anywhere? Does the test have a failure message?

Comment: @battery.cord - have updated the question with the error message. Not very useful though...

Comment: Probably needs to insert something, likely a custom setting or metadata or some kind. Try running your test with `seeAllData=true` - if it passes, there's something required that your test isn't creating.

Comment: Ive added seeAllData to get an opty already inserted and then just update it to give my trigger code coverage. Can't believe I've had to resort to that! Will try and resolve another way when time allows.

Comment: My life was a mess after I installed Eventbrite package. The test class in the package kept failing and i had no support from eventbrite guys.

Comment: @RichardDurrant did you resolve this? I'm getting this exact same issue and cannot view the code as it is hidden.

Comment: @paulK just use seeAllData=true in your testmethods and you should be good. Not ideal but did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Theres probably a dependent object, custom setting, or metadata missing. Hard to tell without seeing whats in the package, or whats being requested in the trigger. You could sniff around the logs/package, or contact their support.

The easy way around this would be to run the test in `seeAllData=true` context. Since your production org already has this object, you should be able to access it for your test.